# Space of multipliers on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

What is the space of multipliers (that is translation invariant bounded operators) on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ (space of continuous functions vanishing at $\pm \infty$)? I suppose the answer should be the set of operators which are a convolution with a (finite) complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  If this is known, is there a reference for this fact?